# Does a broken screen affect the resolution of an android device?

Tags: screen

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 which screen was recently broken. I am trying to use the phone with a third party app on my PC. I tried vysor but the screen resolution is terrible. I also tried the Connect app in windows 10 and I am facing the same problem again. Here are photos of what I mean:

**Connect app screen**

[image: Connect app screen]

**Vysor Screen**

[image: Visor screen]

Is there anyway I can go around the issue?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and improve the title, unless you'd take "no" as a valid answer worth 100 of your reputation :)

Comment: How exactly is your screen broken? Is it just the glass, or is the damage more significant?

Comment: The glass is broken and it seems a little bit lifted upwards. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Vysor, especially for texting with my keyboard. Have you tried messing around in the resolution settings? Click the gear icon in the upper right hand corner of your Vysor screenshot to see this menu:

[image]

There could also be some strange stuff going on with your device. You need to enable USB Debugging from the Developer Options on your Android, which might be tricky if your phone screen is completely broken and unusable. Here's a [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/) link on getting it enabled.

Finally, Windows users need to download some special drivers to get it to work. Download link: http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi

All of this info comes from the [Vysor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.vysor&hl=en_US) page on the Play Store, and some quick Googling.

If you've tried all of this without any luck, we'll need more info about how broken your screen is to help further.

EDIT: I don't have enough reputation to comment below, but I can respond here. How exactly is your screen broken? Is it merely cracked, or is it totally unusable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not a vysor pro user, so I would be grateful if you could suggest another app that could do the job. Also, the screen resolution is fine for any other device, but for my phone it is terrible.

Comment: It does not seem to be a problem with vyosr. I tried the connect app and I have the same problem. I also tried connecting the phone with the TV but nothing new.